# Rails 5 - Using scope method with associated models query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a scope method that queries only records that have been recently updated (or their associated models have been recently updated).  I believe the generated SQL statement looks okay, but I am not seeing any results when there should be some. Thanks for your help!

**Controller**

```
class Api::V1::EncountersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    if params.has_key?(:datestart)
      ...
    elsif params.has_key?(:updated_since)
      date = Date.parse(params[:updated_since])
      respond_with(Encounter.by_updated_since(date),
                  :include => [:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :provider, :insurance],
                  :except => [:facility_id, :physician_id, :encounter_type_id, :group_id, :provider_id, :insurance_id])
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

**Model**

```
    class Encounter < ApplicationRecord
      validates :encounter_type, :physician, :facility, :datetime_start_utc_scheduled, :procedures, :presence => true
      belongs_to :encounter_type
      belongs_to :physician
      belongs_to :facility
      belongs_to :insurance
      belongs_to :group, optional: true
      has_many :encounter_procedures, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :procedures, through: :encounter_procedures
      has_many :actuals, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :providers, through: :actuals

      ...

      scope :by_updated_since, -> updated_at {
        joins(:facility)
        .joins(:physician)
        .joins(:encounter_type)
        .joins(:group)
        .joins(:insurance)
        .where("encounters.updated_at >= ? OR
               facilities.updated_at >= ? OR
               physicians.updated_at >= ? OR
               encounter_types.updated_at >= ? OR
               groups.updated_at >= ? OR
               insurances.updated_at >= ?",
               updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at)}
   ...
   end
```

**Log with generate SQL**

```
app/controllers/api/v1/encounters_controller.rb:12:in `index'
Started GET "/api/v1/encounters?updated_since=2017-08-01" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-10 11:55:01 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::EncountersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"updated_since"=>"2017-08-01"}
  Encounter Load (32.2ms)  SELECT "encounters".* FROM "encounters" INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "encounters"."facility_id" INNER JOIN "physicians" ON "physicians"."id" = "encounters"."physician_id" INNER JOIN "encounter_types" ON "encounter_types"."id" = "encounters"."encounter_type_id" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "encounters"."group_id" INNER JOIN "insurances" ON "insurances"."id" = "encounters"."insurance_id" WHERE (encounters.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR
           facilities.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR
           physicians.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR
           encounter_types.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR
           groups.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR
           insurances.updated_at >= '2017-08-01')
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (0.12ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 31.4ms | ActiveRecord: 32.2ms)
```

Comment: That is a lot of joins you are doing! Maybe you should consider `touch: true` on your `belongs_to` relations (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)

Comment: Also, are these joined relations mandatory? If a `Encounter` record does not have an (existing) associated `Insurance` for example, then the `INNER JOIN` will remove that `Encounter` record from the list. Try using `includes` instead of the `joins`

Comment: I was thinking they were mandatory so that if the associated models where recently updated (and not the Encounter record itself), the Encounter record still show up in the results.

Comment: When I change "joins" to "includes" I get an error ---> "PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "facilities" LINE 2: facilities.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR ^ : SELECT "encounters".* FROM "encounters" WHERE (encounters.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR facilities.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR physicians.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR encounter_types.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR groups.updated_at >= '2017-08-01' OR insurances.updated_at >= '2017-08-01')"

Comment: Try `includes(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance).references(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance).where(...)`

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it.  Submit it as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks for that.   -- How come "includes" and "references" where needed?

Comment: `includes` only triggers another SQL query to grab all records referenced by your scope. Therefore when only doing a `User.includes(:posts).where(conditions)` you cannot *refer* to `:posts` in the `conditions`. Combining `includes` and `references` will do a `LEFT JOIN` on the relations (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your problem**:

The ActiveRecord `joins` make an `INNER JOIN` so `User.joins(:posts)` returns only `User` records having *at least* 1 associated `Post`.

I am pretty sure if you do a simple `Encounter.joins(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance)` it will return an empty list.

**Solution**:

Use `includes` combined with `references` so it will not ignore Encounter records if they have no associated record:

```
Encounter.includes(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance).references(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance).where([...])
```

In your scope:

```
scope :by_updated_since, -> updated_at {
        includes(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance)
        .references(:facility, :physician, :encounter_type, :group, :insurance)
        .where("encounters.updated_at >= ? OR
               facilities.updated_at >= ? OR
               physicians.updated_at >= ? OR
               encounter_types.updated_at >= ? OR
               groups.updated_at >= ? OR
               insurances.updated_at >= ?",
               updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at, updated_at)}
```

**Improvement suggestion**:

```
scope :by_updated_since, ->(updated_at) {
            relations = %i(facility physician encounter_type group insurance)
            sql_cond = relations.map(&:pluralize).map { |table_name| "#{table_name}.updated_at >= :datetime" }.join(' OR ')
            includes(*relations)
            .references(*relations)
            .where(sql_cond, datetime: updated_at) }
```

But I fear that `.references` expects a table_name and not a relation name ...